# Is there a way that a multi-threaded process can continue to run after being core dumped (SIGABRT)?

Tags: linux, multithreading, coredump

I'm running a multi-threaded server application written in c++ with multiple thread listening using thrift on various ports.
After receiving SIGABRT on one of my threads, i noticed logs continue to be written for other thread MINUTES after.
Systemd finally wrote in the journal

```
Mar 02 14:49:17 cs059 systemd[1]: myservice.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Mar 02 14:49:17 cs059 systemd[1]: myservice.service: Killing process 14008 (myservice) with signal SIGKILL.
```

Can you provide me with how such a case could happen and if it can be avoided,  so that all my threads will stop after a core dump is created?

Unfortunately I cannot add the code or the full logs as they are proprietary.